# Null Pointer Exception on Recycler View adapter when binding data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i'm making an app which gets movie data from an API and shows it in a recycler view. I'm using Kotlin with data binding and live data, Retrofit and Moshi. I'm getting a null pointer exception and can't figure out why. The error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.movies, PID: 9560
java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.example.movies.topmovies.MovieAdapter
    at com.example.movies.BindingAdaptersKt.bindRecyclerView(BindingAdapters.kt:11)
    at com.example.movies.databinding.FragmentTopMoviesBindingImpl.executeBindings(FragmentTopMoviesBindingImpl.java:129)
    at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executeBindingsInternal(ViewDataBinding.java:473)
    at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:445)
    at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding$7.run(ViewDataBinding.java:197)
    at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding$8.doFrame(ViewDataBinding.java:291)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:970)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:727)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Here is the Recycler Binding adapter calling (where the error happens):

```
@BindingAdapter("listData")
fun bindRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: List<Movie>?) {
if(data!=null) {
    val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as MovieAdapter
    adapter.submitList(data)
    }
}
```

The error appears in this line:

```
val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as MovieAdapter
```

Here is the adapter class with the DiffCallBack class:

```
class MovieAdapter : ListAdapter<Movie,
    MovieAdapter.ViewHolder>(DiffCallback()){

class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ListViewItemBinding):
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(movie: Movie) {
        binding.movie = movie
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding = ListViewItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)

            return ViewHolder(binding)
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,
                                viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder.from(parent)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val movie = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(movie)
    }
}
class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Movie>() {
override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Movie, newItem: Movie): Boolean {
    return oldItem === newItem
}

override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Movie, newItem: Movie): Boolean {
    return oldItem.id == newItem.id
}}
```

Here is the API service, i am able to get the top 20 movies, which is what i want to display:

```
    private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

interface MovieApiService {

    @GET("top_rated?api_key=f7244e2fd595017cabf28e1e95ab7d31")
    suspend fun getTopMovies(): retrofit2.Response<Response>

}

object MovieApi {
    val retrofitService : MovieApiService by lazy { retrofit.create(MovieApiService::class.java) }
}
```

And finally, here is the fragment layout in which i put the Recycler View:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.movies.topmovies.TopMoviesViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/movies_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:listData="@{viewModel.movies}"
            tools:listitem="@layout/list_view_item" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as MovieAdapter?
```

Notice that question mark in the end.

Comment: I refactored my code to this: `(recyclerView.adapter as MovieAdapter?)?.submitList(data)`  and now i don't get that error anymore. However another popped up: `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout` . The app launches, however there is no recycler view